# Using cut to parse vnstat output

Tags: vnstat

I've been messing with this for a while now and just cannot get it right. I am trying to parse the output of vnstat for log generation using the cut command to pull out the bandwidth usage and packets per second. The raw output looks like it is tab-delimited, but the output I get using the without specifying a delimiter looks like a space. Specifying nothing (tab delimited) or using -d' ' and a -f# for what field doesn't seem to work. Am I going to have to use a regex with this instead?

```
vnstat -i venet0 -tr | grep 'rx' | cut -f1
```

not specifying a delimiter

```
rx 0.06 kbit/s 0 packets/s
```

raw output

```
vnstat -i venet0 -tr
8 packets sampled in 5 seconds
Traffic average for venet0

  rx         0.25 kbit/s             0 packets/s
  tx         0.54 kbit/s             0 packets/s
```

Comment: If you use `awk` (which separates on contiguous whitespace by default) you don't have to worry about exactly what kind of whitespace, and can also avoid the `grep` ex. `awk '$1 == "rx" {print $2,$3}'`

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't thought of using awk instead of cut.

Comment: Assuming you have vnStat version 1.18 or later in use, you can also use the `--json` parameter in combination with `-tr`. That will result the output in being a single json line which can then be parsed easily with, for example, the `jq` command (or also `cut`).

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comment by steeldriver above, the answer is as such:

```
vnstat -i venet0 -tr | awk '$1 == "rx" {print $2,$3}'
```